# Using a matrix as a 'Square Lattice' and activating each adjacent element over time with a defined probability

Tags: r, matlab, nodes, probability, network-analysis

**NOTE:** *The code I provide is in MATLAB, however if you are more proficient in R-studio I am more than happy to take pointers/code for that. I just happen to have slightly better grasp of the syntax of MATLAB with loops.*

I had a previous question on a similar thing I'm doing built up in R-studio:
[Bond Percolation on the square lattice in R-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74009357/bond-percolation-on-the-square-lattice-in-r-studio)

But since I'm more fluent in Matlab I thought I would try and code up what I want from scratch.

So for my code I basically want to do something like this:

- a state vector of length N*N where 0=susceptible, 1=infectious and 2=recovered where a recovered node **CANNOT** be reinfected, for example;
- a loop such that at each time step, the code checks the adjacent neighbours  (NON DIAGONAL) of the first infected node in the list (the state vector), if any are susceptible then apply probability p, and if transmission occurs, update the state vector;
- once all neighbours are checked update the state vector for that infected node from 1 to 2;
  move on to the next infected node;
- the number of infected in each generation is just the number of 1's in the state vector at the end of each time step.

My code as it stands looks like this:

```matlab
%% Setting inital conditions
;
N=6;                % Set initial matrix size
n=3;                % n and m are initial activation node
m=4
t=10;               % time frame of infection
p = 2/3             % probability of transmission
X = zeros(N)        % Set initial matrix using size N
```

```matlab
%% For loop iterating over time t
for i = 1:t
    
    X(n,m) = 1;
    
    if X(n,m) == 1
        % if loops to check if a node is susceptable (equals 0) and if it
        % is assign 0 or 1 based on a predefined probability. (Using
        % binornd(). 
        if n+i > size(X,1)
            break;
        elseif X(n+i,m)==0
            X(n+i,m)= binornd(1,p);
        end
        %
        if m+i > size(X,2);
            break;
        elseif X(n,m+i)==0
            X(n,m+i)= binornd(1,p);
        end
        %
        if n-i < 1
            break;
        elseif X(n-i,m)==0
            X(n-i,m)= binornd(1,p);
        end
        %
        if m-i < 1
            break;
        elseif X(n,m-i)==0
            X(n,m-i)= binornd(1,p);
        end
        
        
    end
    X(n,m) = 2
end
```

So, my code only checks values in a cross shape from the starting node, what I want to do is at each time step of the for loop I want to check ALL values within the matrix for 'infected' nodes' and iterate the if-conditions over each infected node.

**i.e.** at time step 1 we have 1 infected node and each node has 2/3 chance to infect the four nodes around it, in this example we infect 3 nodes at the end of this step the initial infectious node becomes recovered (value 2).

- At time step 2, the three nodes infect their neighbouring nodes and the initial three infectious nodes recover (value 2).
- this repeats until the end of the for loop.

Some bonus points would be to graph these nodes on a square lattice graph or even develop a graph that shows how the number of infected individuals approaches 1 as the probability of infection increases.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You described your problem very well, thanks for that. I am however not sure what your question is? What, of all these steps, are you having trouble with?

Comment: Free bonus point: `imshow` or `imagesc` will show your results with an appropriate colormap and color limits. You can just `infected(t)=sum(X(:)==1)` to add the infected ones at a particular point `t`.

Answer (score 0):

To run a single simulation, here's a vectorized approach that updates the indices of the not-yet-infected and the currently infected each time step. It loops only over the time steps. It returns the lattice state at the end of the simulation.

```
function X = SimInfect(N, n, m, t, p)
% set up constants
    N2 = N + 2;
    idx = 2:N + 1;
    offset = [-1, 1, -N2, N2];
    % the probabilities of becoming infected given i - 1 infected
    % neighbors, with i being the index of P
    P = [0, 1 - (1 - p).^(1:4)];
% set up variables
    I = N2*m + n + 1; % the indices of the currently infected
    % Set up the lattice. Previously infected = NaN. Pad with NaN.
    X = NaN(N2, N2);
    X(idx, idx) = 0;
    X(I) = 1;
    U = find(X == 0); % the indices of the not yet infected
% run the simulation
    for i = 1:t
        % for each not-yet-infected, do they become infected this round?
        bln = rand(1, length(U)) < P(sum(X(U + offset), 2, 'omitnan') + 1);
        X(U(bln)) = 1; % update the state of the newly infected
        X(I) = NaN; % update the state of the previously infected
        I = U(bln); % update the indices of the currently infected
        U = U(~bln); % update the indices of the not-yet-infected
    end

    X = X(idx, idx); % remove the padding
    X(isnan(X)) = 2; % re-code previously infected as 2
end
```

For generating statistics, we can further vectorize over the desired number of replications:

```
function nInfected = SimInfectMult(N, n, m, t, p, reps)
    N2 = N + 2;
    P = [0, 1 - (1 - p).^(1:4)];
    NN = N2^2;
    offset = [-1, 1, -N2, N2];
    I = N2*m + n + 1:NN:NN*reps;
    X = NaN(N2, N2, reps);
    X(2:N + 1, 2:N + 1, :) = 0;
    X(I) = 1;
    U = find(X == 0);

    for i = 1:t
        bln = rand(1, length(U)) < P(sum(X(U + offset), 2, 'omitnan') + 1);
        X(U(bln)) = 1;
        X(I) = NaN;
        I = U(bln);
        U = U(~bln);
    end

    nInfected = N^2 - histcounts(U, 1:NN:NN*(reps + 1));
end
```

100k simulations takes my machine just over a second:

```
>> timeit(@() SimInfectMult(6, 3, 4, 10, 2/3, 1e5))

ans =

    1.2663
```

Also note that the simulation can be initialized with multiple infected, e.g.:

```
X = SimInfect(6, [1, 3], [6, 4], 10, 2/3);
```